# How to style a XUL textbox with CSS :focus

Tags: css, firefox, xul

I'm playing around with a firefox extension written in XUL, and wanted to customize the style of a textbox element.

Here is what I've come so far (CSS file) :

```
textbox.custom-style {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px #CCC inset;
    background: #FFF;
    border : solid 1px #CCC;
}
```

The style applies correctly but when I've added this rule to alter the style a focused textbox, it doesn't seem to work.

```
textbox.custom-style:focus {
    border : solid 1px #ACC;
}
```

I've tried the same rules for a button element and it seems to work OK (when I 'tab' to the button, it gets focus and change its style as expected)

So what am I missing here? Is this a known bug? I've looked around for a bug report or a workaround but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `<textbox>` element, a special attribute `focused` is added whenever the element has the focus. You can check for the presence of this attribute to determine if the element has the focus within a style sheet. It will have the value `true`.

This is because actually focus is in `<html:input>` element which is inside `<textbox>` element.

Comment: so what you mean is that I should add : `textbox.custom-style[focused=true] {}`

Comment: You are right, it works. That should be documented somewhere because it's not so obvious.

Comment: It's documented in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection#Changing_the_focus

Comment: I totally missed that bit of information thanks for the quick answer.